# Pixellating a UIImage returns UIImage with a different size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-image

I'm using an extension to pixellate my images like the following:

```
func pixellated(scale: Int = 8) -> UIImage? {
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: self), let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate") else { return nil }
    filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(scale, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)

    guard let output = filter.outputImage else { return nil }

    return UIImage(ciImage: output)
}
```

The problem is the image represented by `self` here has not the same size than the one I create using `UIImage(ciImage: output)`.

For example, using that code:

```
print("image.size BEFORE : \(image.size)")
if let imagePixellated = image.pixellated(scale: 48) {
    image = imagePixellated
    print("image.size AFTER : \(image.size)")
}
```

will print:

```
image.size BEFORE : (400.0, 298.0)
image.size AFTER : (848.0, 644.0)
```

Not the same size and not the same ratio.

Any idea why?

EDIT:

I added some prints in the extension as following:

```
func pixellated(scale: Int = 8) -> UIImage? {
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: self), let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate") else { return nil }

    print("UIIMAGE : \(self.size)")
    print("ciImage.extent.size : \(ciImage.extent.size)")

    filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(scale, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)

    guard let output = filter.outputImage else { return nil }

    print("output : \(output.extent.size)")

    return UIImage(ciImage: output)
}
```

And here are the outputs:

```
UIIMAGE : (250.0, 166.5)
ciImage.extent.size : (500.0, 333.0)
output : (548.0, 381.0)
```

Comment: What is `ciImage`'s `extent` right after creation? I suspect the issue might be something to do with `self`'s `scale`.

Comment: @ravron I updated the question and added some prints in the extension. Looks like a scale at first yes but can't figure out why the `output` is like this (the ratio is not the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `self.size` is measured in points. `self`'s size in pixels is actually `self.size` multiplied by `self.scale`.
2. The `CIPixellate` filter changes the bounds of its image.

To fix problem one, you can simply set the `scale` property of the returned `UIImage` to be the same as `self.scale`:

```
return UIImage(ciImage: output, scale: self.scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
```

But you'll find this still isn't quite right. That's because of problem two. For problem two, the simplest solution is to crop the output `CIImage`:

```
// Must use self.scale, to disambiguate from the scale parameter
let floatScale = CGFloat(self.scale)
let pixelSize = CGSize(width: size.width * floatScale, height: size.height * floatScale)
let cropRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: pixelSize)
guard let output = filter.outputImage?.cropping(to: cropRect) else { return nil }
```

This will give you an image of the size you want.

Now, your next question may be, "why is there a thin, dark border around my pixellated images?" Good question! But ask a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks Ravron. Works fine. I haven't seen the dark border you are talking about though.